# Render Error on phone <Text> must be rendered within a <Text> component but on browser was fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-go

I am learning React Native and this is an error when trying to setup the whole thing when using Expo Go on my iPhone.

I received this error when I ran `npm start` or `expo-cli start --tunnel` to start Metro Bundler. When I scan it and open Expo Go, I received this error on my VS Code

`ERROR  Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.`

And this error was displayed on my Expo Go on iOS:

[image]

The only code I have so far (because this is only setting up Expo and Metro Bundler before started coding the whole app):

```
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native-web';
    
    const Home = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>HELLO</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    export default Home;
```

in index.js

and

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

const Layout = () => {
    return <Stack/>;
}

export default Layout;
```

in _layout.js

but when I open it on the browser, it appears the correct codes.

How can I resolve this (especially with the error displayed on the phone)?

For further reference, I am following [the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ3bGvy0WAY&t=1227s) and I am stuck at minute 21:00 because of this Render Error.

Comment: In React Native for web, uses React DOM, which can handle plain text as well. However, when it comes to React Native for Mobile the components are rendered Natively for text it's <TextView> in Android and <UITextView> for iOS. And if the Text is outside of Text Comp. then the RN parsing engine would not find the core component for that, and the error occurs. This mismatch leads to the "Text must be rendered within a Text component" error.

Comment: Please check that your code did not contains any spacing or any symbol or text outside of the Text component, and also check your imports as already pointed out by @dejan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is not right:
`import { View, Text } from 'react-native-web';`
It should be:
 `import { View, Text } from 'react-native';`

Note: Not sure how the mistake happened, but be aware of autocomplete options, sometimes it can autocomplete with the wrong import (eg. same component name in different package)

Comment: OMG THIS WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH T_T yes i will sure to be more careful after this 

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have no spaces after the tag `<View>`.
This usually happens when you copy something or just put a space by mistake, it's invisible so you wouldn't notice.

To be sure I'd try to do this:

```js
<View><Text>HELLO</Text></View>
```

If it doesn't work you can delete and restore code until you find the problem. Most probably it will be a empty space